# Dax All function inside AverageX function

Tags: powerbi, dax

Can anyone explain me what does ALL function do below inside function. Does it make relationship between 'Sales' table with 'Product' table?

```
_Sales by Product Column Chart Colour = 

var avgSales = AVERAGEX(
ALL('Product'[Product])

, [Sales Amount]

)

return

IF([Sales Amount] < avgSales, "Dark Blue")
```

Comment: ALL function DAX: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. ALL is a versatile DAX function. It can be used either as a table function or calculate modifier.
Let's analyze the behavior of ALL, first checking your code:

1))
As a Table Function like in your code

```
Sales by Product Column Chart Colour = 
    var avgSales = AVERAGEX(
    ALL('Product'[Product])      
    ,[Sales Amount]
    )
    RETURN
    IF([Sales Amount] < avgSales, "Dark Blue")
```

It returns all the unique values of [Product] column on Product table, and for each row, evaluate sales amount measure. It ignores the filter on product column and calculates overall averages of all products. You know the rest starting with if.

2))
As a calculate modifier like in below measure:

```
Test_Measure = 
CALCULATE(
 SUM(Sales[Amount]),
 ALL(Product)
)
```

It removes all the filters on all the columns of the product table, and affects the filter context directly.

To summarize, It is important where you use ALL. Depending on it, It reacts differently.

I hope this is enough for you to understand its behavior.